# Why does my S3 signed URL not work on the first load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website that is using S3 to host some content like images and JavaScript scripts. I want to limit access to these links, so I use a private S3 bucket and generate a pre-signed URL in the backend and pass that as the link for the image.

The problem comes that when I load the website none of the resources load. If I use the link independently it works fine, so I know for a fact that the permissions in AWS are OK, and that the URL works. Now, when I *reload* the website, everything works fine (the URL hasn't changed)! So I know that the issue isn't with how I add the links to the webpage that gets served (I use NodeJS incase that matters but since its working after a reload, I'm not sure).

So I wanted to ask if there is anything in S3 that I need to consider that might cause such an issue? I have the webapp running on an EC2 instance, so my first though was that the webpage loads before the signed URL actually works, but I don't see how that could be, even if thats how signed URLs work (which I doubt).

Is there a solution to this, other than just making the bucket public (I tested this and it works as a solution but I would really like to avoid it if possible...)?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The comments made me aware of a mistake I made, I somehow missed this major clue, but the link it passes to the webpage on the first try is just a basic S3 link: s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
So now the questions is more: Why does the result of the NodeJS signed URL function return this link?

Comment: Presigned URLs should work the first time they're used.  What errors or failures do you see from the browser's network monitor when you attempt to load the page?

Comment: Do any errors appear in the brower's Console debug page?

Comment: OK, so this is on me, I somehow missed this major clue, but the link it passes to the webpage is just a basic S3 link: https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ So this raises the question, why does the result of the NodeJS signed URL function return this link?

Comment: Can you show a [mre] that elicits that behavior?